# How to add a delete function to angular HTTPClient?

Tags: angular, api, crud

I've been working on angular that links to my back end API. I can retrieve my list of businesses from the back end and post reviews etc. But I am having trouble deleting records. I call the delete function in my by back end and nothing happens.

Comment: Code sample on what you have done would help to give a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the code as below:

Delete.component.html

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="Delete(product)"></button>
```

Delete.component.ts

```
 public Delete(del:products){
this.productservice.Delete(del.bookid)
.subscribe(
  res => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('productview');

  });}
```

Delete.service.ts

```
Delete(id: any) {
return this.http.delete(this.rootUrl + '/Products/' + id);}
```